# Not able to set border of my table through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add border to my table through Javascript. But I get the error

```
"Cannot set property border of undefined"
```

on debugging through Chrome.

Below is the code snippet:

```
 var table = "<table>";
 table.style.border="1px solid red"; // Getting error here

 var content="";
 content += "<tr><th>" + "Booking Id" + "</th> ";
 content += " <th>" + "CCA Sent" + "</th> ";
 content += " <th>" + "CCA Acknowledged" + "</th> ";
 content += "<th>" + "Folio Received" + "</th></tr>";
 content += "</table>";

 table += content;

$(document.body).append(table);
```

I googled it and the most common reason was said to be because of uninitialized variable, but this doesn't seem to be in my case.

Please help me solve this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are trying to set the style property on *table*, it is simply a plain sting. It does not have any style property because the table does not exist in the DOM yet. Set the style property after appending the table to the DOM:

```js
var table = "<table id='myTable'>";
var content="";
content += "<tr><th>" + "Booking Id" + "</th> ";
content += " <th>" + "CCA Sent" + "</th> ";
content += " <th>" + "CCA Acknowledged" + "</th> ";
content += "<th>" + "Folio Received" + "</th></tr>";
content += "</table>";

table += content;

$(document.body).append(table);
document.getElementById('myTable').style.border="1px solid red";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `table` holds a string, hence `table.style` returns undefined, and you cannot set the `border` property of `undefined`.

To address this you need `table` to reference an Element. As you're already using jQuery you can do this by creating a jQuery object and appending that to the DOM. Also note that it's generally considered better practice to add CSS classes to elements in JS instead of amending their inline styling. Try this:

```js
var $table = $("<table><tr><th>Booking Id</th><th>CCA Sent</th><th>CCA Acknowledged</th><th>Folio Received</th></tr></table>").appendTo('body');

$table.addClass('foo');
```

```css
table.foo {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And instead of `$table.addClass('foo');`, we can have `class` already in the markup considering user is not changing it after some event..

Comment: @Rayon very true, although I left that separate in the example as from the context of the question it appears the OP is attempting to add the styling after the table is created.

Comment: Yeah.. Got it 

Answer (score 0):

```
 var table = document.getElementById("your_table_id");
 table.style.border="1px solid red"; // Getting error here

 var content="<table>";
 content += "<tr><th>" + "Booking Id" + "</th> ";
 content += " <th>" + "CCA Sent" + "</th> ";
 content += " <th>" + "CCA Acknowledged" + "</th> ";
 content += "<th>" + "Folio Received" + "</th></tr>";
 content += "</table>";



$('body').append(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var content="<table id='some_id'>";
 content += "<thead><tr><th>" + "Booking Id" + "</th> ";
 content += " <th>" + "CCA Sent" + "</th> ";
 content += " <th>" + "CCA Acknowledged" + "</th> ";
 content += "<th>" + "Folio Received" + "</th></tr>";
 content += "</thead></table>";

$("body").append(content)

var table = document.getElementById('some_id')
table.style.border="1px solid red";
```